# Do packages get transferred across when downloading a new version of python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have just downloaded the latest version of python (using the installer on Windows). I assumed it would replace my old version of python and all packages I had downloaded would get moved across. However, it appears that hasn't happened:

C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32 (old version)

C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32 (new version)

What's the best way to ensure a smooth transition across to the new version? Should I just copy all of the files from site-packages into the new python folder?

I would just like one version of python installed but don't want to delete the old version as worried projects I'm working on (using Pycharm) won't work

Comment: I dont think copying site-packages will work for all the packages. you can do a pip freeze in from Python37-32 and compare them with Python38-32. But installing packages in a root python is not a recommended way to work. You should have a virtual env and have your packages installed in the same. Virtual env created from python 37 can be migrated to work with python 38

Comment: I've got a project set up in a venv in PyCharm, it is using Python 37-32, how would I move this across to Python 38-32 with all the dependent site-packages. Or is the idea of the venv is that I can use Python 38-32 but still be using the site-packages in Python 37-32?

Comment: Check this out - http://barkas.com/2016/change-python-version-in-virtualenvwrapper/ this has steps on how to cleanly move virtual env.